# DIFERENCIA DE DIAS ERROR SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

tengo el siguiente problema en SQL
Estoy utilizando la siguiente linea para obtener los dias de diferencia a la fecha actual.

```
DATEDIFF(DAY, FECHAINGRESO  , @fechaActual)
```

El resultado en ciertos usuarios es correcto, en otros 1 dia de mas.

| FECHAINGRESO | DIASTRANSCURRIDOS |
| --- | --- |
| 2018-02-02 | 1530 |
| 2019-03-11 | 1128 |
| 2019-03-25 | 1114 |
| 2022-04-06 | 6 |
| 2022-04-07 | 5 |

Se agradece cualquier apoyo,
Saludos!

Comment: con los datos que muestras no podemos ver si hay un día de más o no

Comment: Las primeras 3 celdas, tienen un dia de mas.

Comment: sera por las horas? contaste todos los dias a mano?

Comment: correcto, saque calculo ha mano, igual realize un CAST AS DATE , pero se obtiene el mismo resultado

Comment: los resultados están correctos, por qué crees que hay días de más?, tomaste en cuenta los años bisiestos?

Comment: correcto, ese es el detalle.